# Find timeline for duration values in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, duration

I have the following time-series:

```
b = [2 5 110 113 55 115 80 90 120 35 123];
```

Each number in `b` is one data point at a time instant. I computed the duration values from `b`. Duration is represented by all numbers within `b` larger or equal to 100 and arranged consecutively (all other numbers are discarded). A maximum gap of one number smaller than 100 is allowed. This is how the code for duration looks like:

```
 N = 2;     % maximum allowed gap     
 duration = cellfun(@numel, regexp(char((b>=100)+'0'), [repmat('0',1,N) '+'],    'split'));
```

giving the following duration values for `b`:

```
duration = [4 3];
```

I want to find the positions (time-lines) within `b` for each value in `duration`. Next, I want to replace the other positions located outside `duration` with zeros. The result would look like this:

```
result = [0 0 3 4 5 6 0 0 9 10 11];
```

If anyone could help, it would be great.

Comment: _I computed the duration values from b_ Post your code, so it can perhaps be extended to do the other parts you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to original question: pattern with at most one value below 100

Here's an approach using a regular expression to detect the desired pattern. I'm assuming that one value <100 is allowed only between (not after) values >=100. So the pattern is: one or more values >=100 with a possible value <100 in between .

```
b = [2 5 110 113 55 115 80 90 120 35 123]; %// data
B = char((b>=100)+'0'); %// convert to string of '0' and '1'
[s, e] = regexp(B, '1+(.1+|)', 'start', 'end'); %// find pattern
y = 1:numel(B);
c = any(bsxfun(@ge, y, s(:)) & bsxfun(@le, y, e(:))); %// filter by locations of pattern
y = y.*c; %// result
```

This gives

```
y =
     0     0     3     4     5     6     0     0     9    10    11
```

#### Answer to edited question: pattern with at most *n* values in a row below 100

The regexp needs to be modified, and it has to be dynamically built as a function of *n*:

```
b = [2 5 110 113 55 115 80 90 120 35 123]; %// data
n = 2;
B = char((b>=100)+'0'); %// convert to string of '0' and '1'
r = sprintf('1+(.{1,%i}1+)*', n); %// build the regular expression from n
[s, e] = regexp(B, r, 'start', 'end'); %// find pattern
y = 1:numel(B);
c = any(bsxfun(@ge, y, s(:)) & bsxfun(@le, y, e(:))); %// filter by locations of pattern
y = y.*c; %// result
```

Comment: I edited it. It's actually `b>=100`. If there are more than one consecutive numbers in `b<100`, they will be ignored in computing the duration.

Comment: @Bowecho Corrected

Comment: How can I change from one value < 100 to other value (change the maximum allowed gap) in between values >= 100?

Comment: @Bowecho That's trickier. And it depends on whether you allow all those values in a single run or dispersed

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by single run or dispersed.

Comment: For example, if I consider the maximum gap as 2 instead of 1, I would get a `duration = 11` instead of `duration = [4 3]`, so I would get an entire cluster instead of 2 clusters.

Comment: So you allow an _arbitrary_ number of _intermediate_ gaps of _size at most 2 right? Try `[s, e] = regexp(B, '1+(.{1,2}1+)*', 'start', 'end')` maybe

Comment: It seems it's working. So there will be `[s, e] = regexp(B, '1+(.{1,n}1+)*', 'start', 'end')`, with `n` being the adjustable intermediate gap. I tested it for more values of `n`, not just 1 and 2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My bad, it seems that adding `n` doesn't work. You have to put the number as the intermediate gap. Although I don't understand why.

Comment: Great! I'll do that later

Comment: Yes, you need the actual number in the regexp. Or use something like sprintf to build the string from the number

Comment: Edited into the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, not using `regexp`. It naturally generalizes to arbitrary gap sizes and thresholds. Not sure whether there is a better way to fill the gaps. Explanation in comments:

```
% maximum step size and threshold
N = 2;
threshold = 100;
% data
b = [2 5 110 113 55 115 80 90 120 35 123];

% find valid data
B = b >= threshold;
B_ind = find(B);
% find lengths of gaps
step_size = diff(B_ind);
% find acceptable steps (and ignore step size 1)
permissible_steps = 1 < step_size & step_size <= N;
% find beginning and end of runs
good_begin = B_ind([permissible_steps, false]);
good_end = good_begin + step_size(permissible_steps);
% fill gaps in B
for ii = 1:numel(good_begin)
    B(good_begin(ii):good_end(ii)) = true;
end
% find durations of runs in B. This finds points where we switch from 0 to
% 1 and vice versa. Due to padding the first match is always a start of a
% run, the last one always an end. There will be an even number of matches,
% so we can reshape and diff and thus fidn the durations
durations = diff(reshape(find(diff([false, B, false])), 2, []));

% get positions of 'good' data
outpos = zeros(size(b));
outpos(B) = find(B);
```